# How to make a script call itself

Tags: php, api, restart

I have a PHP script that receives and sends a large amount of data through/to an API.  It works correctly, but the API that my script calls sometimes breaks and returns me a **500 Server Error**. In this case I would like to make my script **restart**

How can I do that?
I tried `header("Location: http://example.com/myscript.php");` but with no success.

**EDIT (because of 6 people clicked put this question on hold):**

- ok, so I have my *myscript.php* which should run as a crontab..
- this *myscript.php* sends a large amount of data to a external/remote API (it is not my API, so I can't fix problems here).. but the API sometimes breaks down after a varying amout of data.. (tha data I send I checked and validated)

*myscript.php* firstly asks the API which data was already sent to it and skips that, so when *myscript.php* could restart itself, it will somewhen be finished :)

Comment: If the script breaks, then it wont exactly do anything else. I'd try and identify why the script is breaking in the first place, and focus on fixing that.

Comment: Typically when the script breaks, it stops and you can't run more code. You would have to use something like javascript to perform an ajax call and if the ajax call returns a 500 error, javascript could re-request the page. Like Frankerz said, find why it is causing the error and solve that. You will likely see the issue in the error log (off the top of my head I would say max execution time).

Comment: `Location` redirects cause the browser to issue a `get` on the specified url. if the script was originally called with a POST, then you're not calling it the same way, are NOT passing in whatever data was posted, etc... e.g. restarting in this manner is essentially pointless.

Comment: The call to `header` is pointless though, regardless of get/post. If the server throws a 500 error, the call to header will never run, as php will just stop processing.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are not saying that *your* script fails, but that your script uses a web API which occasionally fails.

If the API is returning an error because of the data you are sending to it, you should reexamine your code to figure out how to prevent creating such data.

On the other hand, if the API randomly fails when you send it data with which it will succeed on subsequent requests, it might be best to stop using the API.

If you are stuck with it for whatever reason and you want to just retry the call instead of aborting your script, I think you could probably do this without restarting the entire script.

```
$max_attempts = 4;  // Decide on a reasonable number of times to retry the call

while ($max_attempts--) {
    // Try the API call up to the specified maximum number of attempts
    $returned_data = $api->call($sent_data);
    // Stop trying when you get a successful response
    if ($returned_data != '500 Server Error') break;
}
```

If the random failure is relatively infrequent, this approach should significantly reduce the overall failure rate. And if you need to repeat certain parts of your code before the API call on subsequent attempts, you can just include them in the retry loop as well.

If you get to the maximum number of retries and still don't have good data, then something unusually bad is probably happening, so you should probably stop trying.

```
if ($returned_data == '500 Server Error') die ("The API probably isn't working at all");
```

Theoretically, if there was a way to restart your entire script each time the API call failed, then if the API did stop working it seems like your script would restart itself in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is what I do in similar situations using 3rd party http requests. I usually sleep a second or two between retries, try 5 times. It had to be a REALLY shitty API to fail that. You could also do something more creative like sleep 2 * $i seconds, so every loop waits longer and longer.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `curl` call to yourserlf, then `exit();`

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/myscript.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
exit();
```

This will cause another instanse of your script to start (you call your url with a GET), force this call to die after 5 seconds instead of waiting the other instance to finish executing, then exit(); with whatever text you may want

EDIT: You might also need to set `ignore_user_abort(true)` to keep your new script from dying when you stop the curl call to execute exit

Comment: may i know what the downvote for? it answers exactly what the question asked.

Comment: This pattern is best avoided. By default, PHP scripts do not continue executing if `ignore_user_abort()` is not set, so the child script will stop running after 5 seconds. Worse, if you're not extremely careful about how you use this, you may end up with a large number of requests running simultaneously, potentially crashing the server.

Comment: … Additionally, some hosting environments may not permit web sites to make recursive calls to themselves, or may limit the number of PHP requests running simultaneously. Using this code will fail in such an environment.

Comment: I'm not saying it is the proper way to go about it, but is still the correct answer to the question asked. As  for the first part, it might or might not work on user abort, on multiple occasions i found it working. and he could always include it for this script only, that is indeed my bad for not including to my answer

Comment: A correct answer to a possibly incorrect question is still a correct answer